# Have trouble running the meteor's bundle

Tags: meteor, bundle

I have a meteor project that runs well by 'meteor'.Then I try to use the bundle to run my meteor project and there're my operations below.

```
/*get the bundle*/
meteor build test/
cd test
tar -zxvf myproject.tar.gz

/*install the node packages and upgrade the node*/
npm install fibers
npm install n
n 0.10.36
/*set the env*/
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://127.0.0.1:31001'
export ROOT_URL='http://localhost:3000'
export PORT=3000

/*run*/
node bundle/main.js
```

It seems like very successful before I open the browser and visit the 'localhost:3000'.
The page shows 
'

```
iron:router
Organize your Meteor application.

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home', {
    data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}); }
  });
});
```

'

I will be appreciate if someone could give me some idea!
ps: I'm so sorry that I haven't enough reputations to show the screen shot...

Comment: You may have an error on the top of your routes file. Try running with `meteor --production` to replicate the behaviour locally and check out your javascript console for errors to find where it's coming from.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful idea.But I still can't find where the error happens , cause it's not failed while I only using the 'meteor' to run the project...

Comment: The error is actually there with `meteor`, but files aren't concatenated so it wont stop your app from working. But the error is still there, if there is an error stopping your routes from being registered. Its likely to do with trying to read data that has not yet arrived. The best bet to find it is to look through the js console and find where it comes from.

Comment: Bravo! After fixing the bug in the js console (Cause there're two duplicate templates in my project), all goes well! Thank you very much! PS: why don't you put your words in the answer that I could 'accepted' your answer for the latter~